# Redirect from /index.html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

At .htaccess I have such a rule to redirect from site.com to www.site.com:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It works fine, but also I need to redirect from site.com/index.html to http://www.site.com
I have add this one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com/index.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But it doesn't work :( Anybody help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index.html$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**Do not forget to clear your browser's cache! Before trying the above.**

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [L,R=301] This working but not this - RewriteRule ^index.html$ / [R=301,L] - I have clear my browser's cache ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

try putting your second condition before the first one and it should work.

EDIT:

try this as your first rule:

```
RewriteRule ^site.com/index.html$ http://www.site.com [L,R=301]
```

(i guess your your 2nd rule is wrong._

Comment: If your suggestion does not work I all the same need to accept it?